# I am trying to debug LWC in chrome dev console

Tags: salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am working on wire service, I get the output on UI (salesforce UI), I want to be able to see the response data in the dev console so that I manipulate the data on template.

Usualy we should be able to see the component in the console. I cannot see my component there. What settings do I enable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the data in console.log which you wanted to see in the console .
example : console.log('DATA', response ) ;
at response you provide your variable name which is containing the data .
for more information you can refer to this website : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.debug_intro